# jquery mobile add/remove class when button touch

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am making a hybrid app using jquery mobile.
I have a button which is add class when touch-start, and remove class when touch-end.

So this is my JS code...

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){ 
    $(document).on('vmousedown','.icGnb1' ,function(){
        $(".icGnb1").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icGnb1").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icGnb1").removeClass('on');
     });  

    $(document).on('vmousedown','.icGnb2' ,function(){
        $(".icGnb2").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icGnb2").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icGnb2").removeClass('on');
     });  

    $(document).on('vmousedown','.icGnb3' ,function(){
        $(".icGnb3").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icGnb3").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icGnb3").removeClass('on');
     });  

    $(document).on('vmousedown','.icGnb4' ,function(){
        $(".icGnb4").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icGnb4").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icGnb4").removeClass('on');
     }); 


     $(document).on('vmousedown','.icM1' ,function(){
        $(".icM1").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icM1").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icM1").removeClass('on');
     }); 

     $(document).on('vmousedown','.icM2' ,function(){
        $(".icM2").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icM2").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icM2").removeClass('on');
     });

     $(document).on('vmousedown','.icM3' ,function(){
        $(".icM3").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".icM3").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".icM3").removeClass('on');
     }); 
});
```

Do I have to make all buttons should be with touch event? 
I mean.. is this right way?

Comment: Can you not assign the same class to each button instead of using different classes? What you're using as classes seem more like ids.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your buttons do the same thing, then your code should be:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){ 

    $(":button").on('vmousedown', function(){
            $("this").addClass('on'); 
        }), on('vmouseup', function(){
            $("this").removeClass('on');
        }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
            $("this").removeClass('on');
        }); 
    });

});
```